# HTML just an image in a row

Tags: html, image, row, block

Im currently moving a blog from one site to another. The problem: sometimes the images wont display as on the old blog. An image should block the row from text. As I am just the Conent-Manger, **Im not allowed to change the .CSS**. See here:

**new** blog (where its wrong): https://boasblogs.org/humboldt/what-do-we-know-when-we-see/

**old** blog (how it should look like): https://blog.uni-koeln.de/gssc-humboldt/was-wissen-wir-wenn-wir-sehen/

My code currenty looks like this:

```html
<img class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-1261" style="display: block;" src="https://boasblogs.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/Abb.1.jpg" alt="" height="820" />

<p style="text-align: center;"><em>Img. 1: Unkown Artist, August the Strong as Chief of Africans,
1709, SKD, Exhibition "Global Players".</em></p>

The exhibition “Miniatur Geschichten” was built around two collections of Indian miniature albums, one of which had belonged to the Indologist August-Wilhelm Schlegel, and that had hibernated in the museum vaults for over two centuries.<a href="#_edn6" name="_ednref6">[vi]</a>

<img class="aligncenter wp-image-1262 size-full" src="https://boasblogs.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/Abb.2.jpg" alt="" height="700" />

<p style="text-align: center;"><em>Img. 2: Unkown Artist, Audience</em> (darbar)<em> of Great Mogul Aurangzeb, Dekkan-Mogul, early 18th century, SKD, Exhibition "</em><em>Miniatur Geschichten".</em></p>

<img class="wp-image-1263 size-full aligncenter" src="https://boasblogs.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/Abb.3.jpg" alt="" height="981" />

<p style="text-align: center;"><em>Img. 3: Portrait of Vizier Abd-al Jafar Beg, 1688-1689, SKD,
Exhibition "Miniatur Geschichten".</em></p>
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Not sure what exactly we _could_ help you with here. The two pages you mentioned look different in a lot of aspects. If you have trouble formatting the content as intended after a switch to a new theme or something, then you should probably talk to the person that is in charge of that aspect of the site?

Comment: The `p` elements wrapping those images on the new site all appear to have the classes `img p.even`, which formats them to float to the left. If you did not add these yourself in the content, it must probably get added by some filter later on or something. If you can not remove that class - then you really need to go talk to the person who is in charge of the theme & stylesheet, and ask them to remove or change that formatting.

Comment: @CBroe Im searching for an attribute or something in the <img> tag, that keeps the all text out of the row, like it is on the old blog. Does this help?

Comment: @CBroe well, thats an important information. I guess you are right, ill talk to the designer. Thank you for your time!

Comment: The `aligncenter` class is what achieves that in the old version - the image is set to `display: block` and the margins set to auto, which centers an element in the available space. That same formatting is in place in the new version as well - but it simply can not work, because the parent paragraphs are floated - which makes them shrink to the width the image itself requires in the first place. The images _are_ technically centered in that space - but because that space is only as wide as the image to begin with, that has no visible effect.

Answer (score 1):

@Peter Gil Delete the float:left on the image, the text will be under the image and you can then center the image.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will decrease body margin of your [New blog](https://blog.uni-koeln.de/gssc-humboldt/was-wissen-wir-wenn-wir-sehen/) like your [Old blog](https://boasblogs.org/humboldt/what-do-we-know-when-we-see/) and the height of the images also use float property in images.

Hope it will help you, thank you